# MS EXCEL inserting records between rows based on a date series in another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two tables/sections on the excel sheet in the below format:

```
Date       Close                         Date         Close
1/3/2011     91                            1/3/2011     94
.....        ...                           ........     ...
.....        ...                           .......      ...
1/18/2011    92                            1/17/2011    97
1/19/2011    92.3                          1/18/2011    97.1
......                                     ........
```

How can I insert the missing date in the left table using the appropriate axcel formulas.

Please note the dates are not sequential.

I can do a vlookup to find all the missing dates, but then inserting them into the rows one by one can be quite time consuming.

Is there some fill series that mimics such behaviour. Am happy to have NA on the Close column's value for the inserted date.

Comment: Are the values in the `Close` column static (i.e. no formula) or the result of a formula that references the date?

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook The close column is static

Answer (score 1):

there is a square in the right bottom corner of a cell, when it is selected.
Select the cell with the date "1/3/2011", "click&hold" the square in the right bottom corner of this cell and pull down.

This should autofill the cells with the right date values.

Best regards

Edit:

Is the following scenario possible?

I added "1/16/2011    xx.x" to the left table.

Does "1/17/2011  97" have to be between "1/16/2011    xx.x" and "1/18/2011    92 "?

```
Date       Close                         Date         Close
1/3/2011     91                            1/3/2011     94
.....        ...                           ........     ...
.....        ...                           .......      ...
1/16/2011    xx.x                          ........     ... 
1/18/2011    92                            1/17/2011    97
1/19/2011    92.3                          1/18/2011    97.1
......                                     ........
```

Comment: Sorry, i think i missed on one point.The dates are not sequential.

Comment: i missunderstood your question too... The missing Date is "1/17/2011  97" and this one you want to add to the left "table"!? So you want a compare between the left and the right "table"!?

Comment: Yes thats right. I want to compare the left and right table.

Comment: I can do a vlookup to get a feel of the missing dates. But what i wnat is really new blank rows to be inserted  for the dates that are missing in left table

Comment: Ah right, think I misunderstood the question to.  Thought you wanted all dates from 3rd January to 19th January to appear in correct place, but  you want the dates and values on the right to be placed in their correct place in the table on the left?  What happens with duplicate dates with a different `Close` value?

Comment: i do not know why my answer is upvoted. It does not solve the problem of asimo, because i missunderstood his question. I asked for additional information via edit my answer...still waiting for additional information!